# Calculate size of resulting array (matrix transformation)

Tags: matlab, matrix, transformation

So I have this code to rotate and skew an image. it works well for the rotation, and the image will fit exactly in the canvas. However if I apply skewing the image doesn't fit anymore. Can someone explain how to calculate the proper array dimension for the resulting image rotated and skewed by specific angles? In particular, I'm using this 2 lines for the rotated image (and it works although I don't fully understand them). How should I modify them such as even when skewed, the final image will fit? Thanks!

```
rows_new = ceil(rows_init_img * abs(cos(rads)) + cols_init_img * abs(sin(rads)));                      
cols_new = ceil(rows_init_img * abs(sin(rads)) + cols_init_img * abs(cos(rads)));
```

full code

```
clc;
clear;

%% init values

%loading initial image
init_img = imread('name2.png');

% define rows/cols dimension of original image pixel matrix
[rows_init_img, cols_init_img,z]= size(init_img); 

% skew angle in radians
sk_angle = 50;
sk_rads = 2*pi*sk_angle/360;

% rotation angle in radians
angle = 20;
rads = 2*pi*angle/360;  

%% calculate size of final_image
orig_corners = [ 1, 1; 1, rows_init_img; 1, cols_init_img; rows_init_img, cols_init_img];
new_corners = uint8(zeros(size(orig_corners)));

for i = 1:size(orig_corners, 1)
    for j = 1:size(orig_corners, 2)
        % translate
        a = i - final_origin_x;
        b = j - final_origin_y;

        % rotate
        x = a * cos(rads) - b * sin(rads);
        y = a * sin(rads) + b * cos(rads);

        % skew along x axis (AFTER rotation)
        x = x + sk_rads * y;

        % translate
        x = x + init_origin_x;
        y = y + init_origin_y;

        % round to turn values to positive integers
        x = round(x);
        y = round(y);

        if (x >= 1 && y >= 1 && x <= size(orig_corners, 1) && y <= size(orig_corners, 2) ) 
          new_corners(i, j) = init_img(x, y);  
        end
    end
end

% calculating array dimesions such that rotated image gets fit in it exactly.
% rows_new = ceil(rows_init_img * abs(cos(rads)) + cols_init_img * abs(sin(rads)));                      
% cols_new = ceil(rows_init_img * abs(sin(rads)) + cols_init_img * abs(cos(rads)));  

% define an array with calculated dimensions and fill the array  with zeros ie.,black
% uint8 is important. without it will show noise WHY?
final_img = uint8(zeros([rows_new cols_new 3 ]));

%calculating center of original image
init_origin_x = ceil(rows_init_img/2);                                                            
init_origin_y = ceil(cols_init_img/2);

%calculating center of final image
final_origin_x = ceil( size(final_img, 1)/2 );
final_origin_y = ceil( size(final_img, 2)/2 );

%% main loop

% apply transformation to each pixel of the image
for i = 1:size(final_img ,1)
    for j = 1:size(final_img, 2)                                                       

        % translate
        a = i - final_origin_x;
        b = j - final_origin_y;

        % rotate
        x = a * cos(rads) - b * sin(rads);
        y = a * sin(rads) + b * cos(rads);

        % skew along x axis
        x = x + sk_rads * y;

        % translate
        x = x + init_origin_x;
        y = y + init_origin_y;

        % round to turn values to positive integers
        x = round(x);
        y = round(y);

        % make sure values exists (are part of the initial image) and copy
        % them in the final image matrix
        if (x >= 1 && y >= 1 && x <= size(init_img, 1) && y <= size(init_img, 2) ) 
          final_img(i, j, :) = init_img(x, y, :);  
        end

    end
end

%% display images

% original image
% figure('name','Original Image','numbertitle','off');
% imshow(init_img);

% result image
figure('name','Manipulated Image','numbertitle','off');
imshow(final_img);
```

updated code

```
clc;
clear;

%% init values

%loading initial image
init_img = imread('name2.png');

% define rows/cols dimension of original image pixel matrix
[rows_init_img, cols_init_img, z]= size(init_img); 

% skew angle in radians
sk_angle = 50;
sk_rads = 2*pi*sk_angle/360;

% rotation angle in radians
angle = 20;
rads = 2*pi*angle/360;  

%calculating center of original image
init_origin_x = ceil(rows_init_img/2);                                                            
init_origin_y = ceil(cols_init_img/2);

%% calculate size of final_image
orig_corners = [ 1, 1; 1, rows_init_img; 1, cols_init_img; rows_init_img, cols_init_img];
new_corners = uint8(zeros(size(orig_corners)));

for i = 1:size(orig_corners, 1)
    for j = 1:size(orig_corners, 2)
        % translate
        a = i - final_origin_x; %at this point I don't have this variable because I can't create it yet
        b = j - final_origin_y;

        % rotate
        x = a * cos(rads) - b * sin(rads);
        y = a * sin(rads) + b * cos(rads);

        % skew along x axis (AFTER rotation)
        x = x + sk_rads * y;

        % translate
        x = x + init_origin_x;
        y = y + init_origin_y;

        % round to turn values to positive integers
        x = round(x);
        y = round(y);

        if (x >= 1 && y >= 1 && x <= size(orig_corners, 1) && y <= size(orig_corners, 2) ) 
          new_corners(i, j) = init_img(x, y);  
        end
    end
end

% calculating array dimesions such that rotated image gets fit in it exactly.
rows_new = abs(max(new_corners(1, :)) - min(new_corners(1, :)));
cols_new = abs(max(new_corners(2, :)) - min(new_corners(2, :)));

% define an array with calculated dimensions and fill the array  with zeros ie.,black
final_img = uint8(zeros([rows_new cols_new 3 ]));

%calculating center of final image
final_origin_x = ceil( size(final_img, 1)/2 );
final_origin_y = ceil( size(final_img, 2)/2 );


%% main loop

% apply transformation to each pixel of the image
for i = 1:size(final_img ,1)
    for j = 1:size(final_img, 2)                                                       

        % translate
        a = i - final_origin_x;
        b = j - final_origin_y;

        % skew along x axis (BEFORE rotation)
         a = a + sk_rads * b;

        % rotate
        x = a * cos(rads) - b * sin(rads);
        y = a * sin(rads) + b * cos(rads);

        % skew along x axis (AFTER rotation)
        %x = x + sk_rads * y;

        % translate
        x = x + init_origin_x;
        y = y + init_origin_y;

        % round to turn values to positive integers
        x = round(x);
        y = round(y);

        % make sure values exists (are part of the initial image) and copy
        % them in the final image matrix
        if (x >= 1 && y >= 1 && x <= size(init_img, 1) && y <= size(init_img, 2) ) 
          final_img(i, j, :) = init_img(x, y, :);  
        end

    end
end

%% display images

% original image
% figure('name','Original Image','numbertitle','off');
% imshow(init_img);

% result image
figure('name','Manipulated Image','numbertitle','off');
imshow(final_img);
```

Comment: The ultimately easy way of doing this is applying the transformation to the 4 corners of the image, and getting the maximum distance between extrema

Comment: could you provide some example code?

Comment: Its a pretty easy thing, what are you struggling with?

Comment: so I've updated my code, I am replicating the same code I had for the transformation, by only using the original corners translated to the "after-tranform" position. Is that correct? How do I set the size of the final image now?

Comment: Well, if oyu have 4 transformed corners, you have 4 X and 4 Y positions where the image is. To fit the whole image, you need to make sure that it fits minimum `abs(max(x)-min(x))` amount of rows, and the same with `y` for columns

Comment: sorry I'm not sure I'm following you. I'm very new to all this. So, how can I get the minimum x value from my new_corners matrix? I mean, if it was a plain array max(array) would work, but as the x, y values are mixed up, how do I separate them?

Comment: What do you mean "mixed up"? Like in... an array?

Comment: if I now write max(new_corners) what I get is the highest value in the whole matrix. But I want the highest value for the x and for the y separately if I'm not mistaking it

Comment: Yes, by using the very basic MATLAB code `max(new_corners(:,1))` you can select the first column. Similar for other columns. Similarly you can replace all your for loops for vectorized code, but thats a different story

Comment: good I', very new and I didn't know I could do that. However there's a logical issue now. In the tranform (translate) I need the final_origin_x and y for it to work. But now I don't have them. I've updated the code with what I have now

Comment: What approaches did you find when you researched this problem? Have you tried implementing any of those approaches? What sorts of problems did you run into with those implementations?

Comment: I haven't found anything specific. That's why I'm here. I'm not even sure how to describe the problem